# Reading CSV File and using Surf to plot time series-data

Tags: matlab, csv

I have 3 csv files which contains co-ordinates X, Y and Z resp. I am trying to plot them in matlab using surf function.  These co-ordinates are recorded against time,

For eg.  FirstX.csv, contains,

```
                                 10,20,30
                                 20,30,40
                                 20,30,40
```

Each row in this file is X coordinate against record time.
Similary for FirstY.csv and FirstZ.csv

I tried something like following,

```
X=csvread(FirstX.csv)
Y=csvread(FirstY.csv)
Z=csvread(FirstZ.csv)

surf(X,Y,Z)
```

gives error saying "Data Dimensions must agree"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will find an answer on the [matlab help page here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/representing-a-matrix-as-a-surface.html). I reproduce its relevant example below. You will have to repeat these steps for each time point.

One the many solutions to achieve a surface plot with `X,Y,Z` vectors is :

-Generate unevenly sampled data within the range [-8, 8] and use it to evaluate the function:

```
x = rand(100,1)*16 - 8;
y = rand(100,1)*16 - 8;
r = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2) + eps;
z = sin(r)./r;
```

-The linspace function provides a convenient way to create uniformly spaced data with the desired number of elements. The following statements produce vectors over the range of the random data with the same resolution as that generated by the -8:.5:8 statement in the previous sinc example:

```
xlin = linspace(min(x),max(x),33);
ylin = linspace(min(y),max(y),33);
```

-Now use these points to generate a uniformly spaced grid:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xlin,ylin);
```

-The key to this process is to use scatteredInterpolant to interpolate the values of the function at the uniformly spaced points, based on the values of the function at the original data points (which are random in this example). This statement uses the default linear interpolation to generate the new data:

```
f = scatteredInterpolant(x,y,z);
Z = f(X,Y);
```

-Plot the interpolated and the nonuniform data to produce:

```
figure
mesh(X,Y,Z) %interpolated
axis tight; hold on
plot3(x,y,z,'.','MarkerSize',15) %nonuniform
```

You may alternatively use the matlab's functions [`griddata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html), [`TriScatteredInterp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterp.html), or [`gridfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit) from the File Exchange - the newly introduced matlab's function `scatteredInterpolant` being the most advanced solution.

Comment: scatteredInterpolant is ot valid function in matlab ?

Comment: @pradeep It is, see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolantclass.html. It may be a newish functionality that's not available if you are using an older version of MATLAB.

Comment: yes, it's old version, @Magla, I will try this solution, thanks

Comment: You may use `TriScatteredInterp` for an older version of matlab, or [`gridfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit) from the File Exchange.